# Carregar arquivo PDF ou P7S no XML

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho a seguinte linha em XML de um Schema XML.

```
{**<nomeArquivoP7S><nomeArquivoP7S>**}
```

e desejo incluir um arquivo em p7s  de nome `copia1.pdf.p7s` nesta linha, isto é
quero carregar este arquivo no XML para ser transmitido ficando da seguinte forma:

```
{**<nomeArquivoP7S>copia1.pdf.p7s<nomeArquivoP7S>**}
```

O que entendo é que ele terá que ler o diretorio onde está, localizar o arquivo e carregá-lo?

Seria mais ou menos assim?

```
string fichaconcatenada = fileName + ".pdf.p7s";

//string str = arroba + Caminhoconcatenado + fichaconcatenada;
string str = Caminhoconcatenado + "\\" + fichaconcatenada;

//string[] words = { arroba,"\\Imagens_SEFAZ\\", fichaconcatenada };
//var res = words.Aggregate((current, next) => current + "\\" + next);
FileStream stream =  new FileStream(@str, FileMode.Open);

// instanciando a variável do tipo BinaryReader
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

// variáveis recebendo os valores lidos pelo arquivo binário
int lendointeiro = reader.ReadInt32();
string lendotexto = reader.ReadString();
Byte lendobool = reader.ReadByte();
//double conteudoArquivoP7S = reader.ReadDouble();
// fecha o acesso com o arquivo
reader.Close();
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fichaconcatenada);
var conteudoArquivoP7S = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

O detalhe é que ao fazer isso, ele me traz somente o conteúdo em binário e não o nome+conteúdo.

Como fazer?

Comment: A pergunta está bem confusa, você quer que o nome do arquivo acompanhe o conteúdo em binário? Não poderia criar(caso não exista) uma tag nesta xml para coloar o nome do arquivo? Tenta adicionar o xml entre aspas simples `` o resulta é `entre aspas simples`

Comment: Vamos ver se consigo ser claro.Tenho o campo (linha) em XLM no seguinte formato:{**<nomeArquivoP7S><nomeArquivoP7S>**} e quero subir o arquivo já escaneado e em PDF bem como convertido em Binario para o campo, mas com o nome do PDF e nao em binario.Tenho uma aplicação que sobre já neste formato mas o conteudo sobe em binario.Este novo projeto quer que eu anexe o binário mas com o nome original...Nao sei se fui claro...Assim    ...{**<nomeArquivoP7S>nomeescolhido1<nomeArquivoP7S>**}